# Cannot update all columns using looping

Tags: php, mysql, activerecord

i have some data to update, and I want to update all the rows in my table using that data. So I tried to get all my data, then loop through my data and set the rows using new data, but it only works for the first row. How do I update all my rows?

this is my code, i using activerecord to update:

```
$replaceid = $_POST['pid'];
$product = ProductModel::find()->where(['createdby'=>$uid])->orWhere(['modifiedby'=>$uid])->all();

  if(isset($product)) {
     foreach ($product as $p) {
       $p->createdby = $replaceid;
       $p->modifiedby = $replaceid;

       $p->update(false);
     }
  }
```

this is only update `createdby` but for `modifiedby` still same.. what's wrong here?

Comment: Does `$replaceid` is not equal to initial value of `modifiedby` (before updating)?

Comment: @Akina yes, it's different value before

Comment: Enable General Log on your MySQL temporarily and look what SQL query is received by MySQL from the program really.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done completely on the database-side, therefore negating any issues you might have in PHP

```
ProductModel::query()->where(['createdby'=>$uid])->orWhere(['modifiedby'=>$uid])->update(['createdby' => $replaceid, 'modifiedby'=> $replaceid]);
```